# Modeling an Acoustic Reflection from a Wall

Tags: acoustics, reflection, geometric-optics, signal-processing

I am trying to simulate the reflection of a sound ray, that goes from a sound source, bounces off a wall, and is received by a microphone.
[image]

The wall has a an absorption coefficient, and a specular reflection coefficient, both of which vary by frequency. Thus, the sound reflected by the wall specularly can be characterized by a certain frequency response curve.

LTI filters are characterized by a frequency response and a phase response. Thus, we can treat the contribution of the wall's specular reflection as a LTI filter (applied to the source signal) if we know the correct phase response.

The reflection path (shown in red above) corresponds to a time delay proportional to the length of the path. If we assume a constant time delay across the frequency spectrum we get a linear-phase filter, that is symmetric about the time-delay corresponding to the reflection path length.

However, this filter clearly has "anti-causal" components: the filter is nonzero before the red line. Thus, the filter begins to have an effect on the signal before the length of the reflection path would suggest that it should.

It seems that either the assumption of constant time delay across the frequency spectrum must be wrong then? If so, I wonder what the correct phase response of the filter is.
[image]

Comment: Having a non-causal filter as your model is not a problem, per se, unless you want to realize it in a real time signal processing. This issue will automatically take care of itself if your model is an FIR one. If not, that is an IIR, then you can always make it essentially causal by adding a fixed time delay that is larger than the "earliest" significant negative time piece in the impulse response. But this is not "physics" and it would be better to ask this question at the https://dsp.stackexchange.com/, so do not be surprised if your question will get closed here.

Comment: I don't see any non-causal parts in the plot. There might be some but it seems its amplitude must be very small. There is indeed some pre-ringing but this is not non-causal as it is well beyond the zero-time.